# Parse received GCM message

Tags: java, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to extract information from a received GCM message. Here is the message sent from my server:

```
 "Message(data: {profile={"id":"214","name":"Dr Who","phone_number":"214"}})"
```

And the message received on the phone:

```
05-24 21:00:26.083: D/GCMIntentServiceReceived Message:(3929): Received Message: Message(data: {profile={"id":"214","name":"Dr Who","phone_number":"214"}})
```

Here is the code I have been using to try and extract the key / value pairs.

```
@Override
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

        String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        JSONFingerprint fingerprintProfile = null;

        Log.d(TAG + "Received Message: ", "Received Message: " + message.toString());

        //System.out.println("PHONE " + intent.getExtras().getString("id")); This returns null


    }
```

I am trying to extract the "id" field in this example but I always get NULL. Does anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'id' is part of the JSON encapsulated in the String message. You should convert the String message to a JSON object and then retrieve 'id'.

```
String[] parts = message.split("=");
try {
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(parts[1].substring(0, parts[1].length() - 2));
String id = object.getString("id");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Beware that the code above is *very* un-generic. You should try to send a clean json-string from the server and skip the string-cutting bit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! It seems the issue was cause by sending the GCM message using a PHP script. Switched back to pure Java and it works fine!